# Why does my output content output twice in the blade php?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement live search bar. The live search is working but it however outputs the output content twice, which is annoying. Could you please have a look where the problem is? Thanks.

Here is my code for the search function.

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            
            $output = "";
            $projects = Project::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                        ->where('module_code',$request->module_code)
                        ->get();
            $count = count($projects);
            // $projects = array_unique($projects);
            if ($projects) {
                foreach ($projects as $project) {
                    $output .= '<tr>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->team_number . '</td>' .
                        // '<td>' . $count . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->lab . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . '<a href="/projects/' . $project->id . '" style="display:block;"><b>' . $project->title . '</b></a>' . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project-> latest_state. '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->team_member_1 . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->latest_team_member_1_state . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->team_member_1 . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->latest_team_member_1_state . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->team_member_1 . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->latest_team_member_1_state . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->ta . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $project->created_at . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' .
                        '<button class="btn-sm btn-info pull-left" onclick="location.href = \'/projects/' . $project->id . '\'">Project Details</button> ' .
                        '</td>' .
                        '</tr>';
                }
                return Response($output);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the script for live search in php blade:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const getQueryParams = (params, url)=>{
        let href = url;
        let regexp = new RegExp('[?&]' + params + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        let qString = regexp.exec(href);
        return qString ? qString[1] : null;
    }
    $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
        $value = $(this).val();
        //alert($value);
        $qString = getQueryParams('module', window.location.href);
        $queryString = 
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
            data : {'search':$value, 'module_code', $qString},
            success:function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                //alert(data);
                $('tbody').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here is the code for search bar in php blade

```
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
                    </div>
```

Before searching:
[image]

After searching:
[image]

Comment: How does the code of the actual blade file look where you output the search results? And what do you get if you dd($projects)?

Comment: Try to debug the output before returning and find that is the problem in the front side or in the back-end. You can use `dd($output)` for dump the state of the variable.

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost, the website does not react if i try to dd($output) just before the return statement.

Comment: @HamidHaghdoost and it shows a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: @NickSdot Thanks for your help. I tried to dd($projects), but the website does not react. I have put my code for the whole blade file online, the link is [link](https://onecompiler.com/posts/3xy39rm78/php-blade-for-staff) _italic_ **bold**. Try "Ctrl+F" to search for "@sortablelink", it will approximately bring you to where the output field starts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, I just found out what's causing the problem. It's kind of silly. The original code is here: https://onecompiler.com/posts/3xy39rm78/php-blade-for-staff, the bug is still up there. The problem was that, I added an additional  tag that is unnecessary. The output is placed wherever there is a  tag as the script was:

```
        $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
        $value = $(this).val();
        $qString = getQueryParams('module', window.location.href);
        $queryString = 
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
            data : {'search':$value, 'module_code': $qString},
            // data : {'search':$value},
            success:function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                // alert(data);
                $('tbody').html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

At the very last bit of the code, it tells html to print result at the  tag(I'm not sure if this is right). By deleting the additional tbody tag, the problem was solved.

Comment: By the way the tbody flag is in line 213